# Issues summing the length of all the words in a text file using pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I am trying to sum up all the letters in a text file using pyspark on databricks. I have succeeded in getting the length of each word but struggling to sum them up

sample text file

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a leo massa. Phasellus maximus
```

Code

```
lee_file = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/lee.txt")
lee_counts = lee_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 
len(word)))

counts_df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(lee_counts).toDF("word", "len")
display(counts_df2.take(10))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pyspark sql's sum function.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum

total_count_df = counts_df2.select(sum("len"))
```

To get count into variable, use collect.

```
total_count = total_count_df.collect()[0][0]
```

Comment: please what does this mean [0][0]

Comment: Also, Please how do I calculate the total number of characters in the file

Comment: .collect() returns the result as array. When you use sum function it returns the result in a column. [0][0] is just accessing the first row, first column value of the returned array

Comment: WHat do you mean by total number of characters?

Comment: from the sample text file.. I want to add all the letters of the words including space or any punctuation maek